# Update javascript data on drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I am working on an employee scheduling application with a django backend and only jquery clientside. I have a table where each row is an employee and each column is a date. Inside each `<td>` can be a `<div>` that is a graphical representation of the shift. The divs are draggable/droppable into other cells.

My question is this: How can i store the shift data client-side and update it when a shift is dragged to another employee or date?

Currently i use JQuery UI to handle the dragging and dropping, django templating to create the table, and the actual DOM to hold the data(`<span>` to hold start time, accessed by the innerHTML, etc...). I want to have some javascript object which is updated when its corresponding graphical object is dragged to another cell.

There are no requirements on technologies to use for this application, so any suggestions for other technologies are welcome, but i would prefer to stick with Django and Python in the backend.

Related Code:
 Shift HTML Object

```
<div class="shift draggable-shift">
<span style="display:none">{{id}}</span>
<div class="shift-top">
    <p class="shift-text">
        <span>{{start_time}}</span> - <span>{{end_time}}</span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="shift-bottom">
    <p class="shift-text">
        {{role}}
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

The date and employee are found by IDs on the `<td>` containing the shift(ex. 1-2009-12-14 -> employeeID-date) and the start_time, end_time, shift-id, and role are found from the template generated markup.

The javascript to extract the data:

```
var draggable = ui.draggable;
draggable.parent().html('');
$(this).html(draggable);
draggable.css("left","");
draggable.css("top","");
draggable.css("position","");
draggable.draggable();
console.log($(this).attr('id'));
id = draggable.children()[0].innerHTML;
start = draggable.children()[1].children[0].children[0].innerHTML;
end = draggable.children()[1].children[0].children[1].innerHTML;
role = draggable.children()[2].children[0].innerHTML;
console.log(id + start + end);
var shift = {};
//shift["id"] = id; 
shift["start"] = start;
shift["end"] = end;
shift["role"] = role;
shift["employee"] = $(this).attr("id").substring(0,1);
shift["date"] = $(this).attr("id").substring(2);
modified["changed"][id] = shift;
j = JSON.stringify(modified);
console.log(modified);
console.log(j);
```

Comment: Using jQuery UI Sortable/Draggable? And, show some code/markup.

Comment: I am using jQuery UI Draggable/Droppable, not sortable. I just remove the html from the previous `<td>` and add it to the new `<td>`.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually come accross the answer myself that works much better.

Using jQuery's `.data()` function, you can add data to a DOM object that is not accessible from the user.